# Tensorflow always predict the same output

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

So, I'm trying to learn tensorflow and, for that, I try to create a classifier for something that, I think, is not so hard.
I'd like to predict if a number is odd or even.
The problem is that Tensorflow always predict the same output, I searched answers the last days but nothing helped me...
I saw the following answers : -[Tensorflow predicts always the same result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36127436/tensorflow-predicts-always-the-same-result)

-[TensorFlow always converging to same output for all items after training](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40451874/tensorflow-always-converging-to-same-output-for-all-items-after-training)

-[TensorFlow always return same result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41123862/tensorflow-always-return-same-result)

Here's my code:

in:

```
df
    nb  y1
0   1   0
1   2   1
2   3   0
3   4   1
4   5   0
...
19  20  1

inputX = df.loc[:, ['nb']].as_matrix()
inputY = df.loc[:, ['y1']].as_matrix()
print(inputX.shape)
print(inputY.shape)
```

out:

(20, 1)
(20, 1)

in:

```
# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.00000001
training_epochs = 2000
display_step = 50
n_samples = inputY.size


x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])   
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, 1]))           
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))            
y_values = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, W), b)      
y = tf.nn.relu(y_values)                 
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,1])  

# Cost function: Mean squared error
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(y_ - y, 2))/(2*n_samples)
# Gradient descent
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# Initialize variabls and tensorflow session
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

for i in range(training_epochs):  
    sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: inputX, y_: inputY}) # Take a gradient descent step using our inputs and labels

    # Display logs per epoch step
    if (i) % display_step == 0:
        cc = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x: inputX, y_:inputY})
        print("Training step:", '%04d' % (i), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(cc)) #, \"W=", sess.run(W), "b=", sess.run(b)

print ("Optimization Finished!")
training_cost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x: inputX, y_: inputY})
print ("Training cost=", training_cost, "W=", sess.run(W), "b=", sess.run(b), '\n')
```

out:

```
Training step: 0000 cost= 0.250000000
Training step: 0050 cost= 0.250000000
Training step: 0100 cost= 0.250000000
...
Training step: 1800 cost= 0.250000000
Training step: 1850 cost= 0.250000000
Training step: 1900 cost= 0.250000000
Training step: 1950 cost= 0.250000000
Optimization Finished!
Training cost= 0.25 W= [[ 0.]] b= [ 0.]
```

in:

```
sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: inputX })
```

out:

```
array([[ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.]], dtype=float32)
```

I tried to play with my Hyper parameters like, the learning rate or the number of training epochs.
I changed the activation function from softmax to relu.
I changed my dataframe to have more examples but nothing happened.
I also tried to add random for my Weights, but nothing changed, the cost was just starting to a higher value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From giving a quick look at the code, it looks ok to me (maybe a part initializing the weights to zero, usually you want a small number different from zero to avoid a trivial solution), while I don't think that you can fit the problem of the parity of integers with a linear regression.

The point is that you are trying to fit

```
x % 2
```

with predictions of the form

```
activation(x * w + b)
```

and there is no way to find good `w` and `b` to solve this problem.

Another way to understand this is to plot your data: the scatter plot of the parity of `x` are two lines of points, and the only way to fit them with a line is with a flat line (that will have a high cost anyway).

I think it would be better to change data to start with, but if you want to address this problem, you should obtain some result using a sine or a cosine as activation function.

Comment: Tanks ! I will try with other datas, and with a random starting weight.

Comment: Very old question/answer, but why could initializing zero weights cause an issue?  I posted a similar question here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/64520/tensorflow-model-works-for-classification-but-not-for-regression-all-prediction if you’re interested in taking a look.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem that I see is that you initialize your weights in the W matrix with 0s. The operation that you have in the linear layer is basically Wx + b. Hence the gradient with respect to x is W. If you start now with zeros for W then the gradient is 0 as well and you are not able to learn anything. Try to use random initial values as stated on tensorflow.org

```
# Create two variables.
weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, 200], stddev=0.35),
                      name="weights")
biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([200]), name="biases")
```

Answer (score 2):

first of all I have to admit that I never used tensorflow. But I think you have a modelling problem here.

You are using the simplest network architecture possible (a 1-dimensional  [perceptron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron)). You have two variables (w and b) which you want to learn and your decision rule for the output looks like

[image: decision formula of the pereceptron]

if you subtract the b and divide by w you get

[image: rearraged decision rule]

So you are basically looking for a threshold to seperate odd and even numbers. No matter how you choose w and b you will always misclassify half of the numbers.

Although decinding if a number is odd or even seems to be a super trivial task for us humans it is not for a single perceptron.